# Black Derman Toy model: from tree to differential equation

Tags: interest-rates, binomial-tree, hullwhite, black

The Black Derman Toy model of interest rates is usually introduced as the model governed by the stochastic differential equation: 
$$d \ln r = \left[\theta(t) + \cfrac{\sigma'(t)}{\sigma(t)}\ln r \right]dt + \sigma(t) dz$$
However, originally the model was developed using binomial trees. The [Black-Derman-Toy paper](http://marshallinside.usc.edu/dietrich/FAJ-1990-BlackDermanToy-OneFactor.pdf) does not contain any differential equation. How does one show that the model constructed using binomial trees corresponds to the above differential equation in the continuous limit?

In a number of articles, for example the Black-Karasinski paper, the derivation is attributed to Hull and White's 1990 article "Pricing interest-rate derivative securities", but it does not give the derivation, only states it as a fact. I have looked into other papers of Hull and White available from John Hull's [website](http://www-2.rotman.utoronto.ca/~hull/DownloadablePublications/index.html), but did not find anything.

Comment: I asked the same question before, I can't deduce the relation between the drift  and diffusion terms through the BDT tree method. But no one answered me.

Comment: @A.Oreo: thanks for the comment. I am thinking of writing to John Hull.

Comment: Why don't you tweet Emanuel Derman? He is incredibly kind and generous.

Answer (score 5):

From the gentleman and scholar Emanuel Derman. Emanuel states "the last two pages answer the question asked".

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cg299qsbquuqdru/TwitterNotesOnBDT.2017.pdf?dl=0&m=

Please thank him directly on Twitter.